# C Preprocessor conditional with extended macros and typecast

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

For a microcontroller, I use macros for the HAL. Now, to generalise the use of the HAL, I want to do something like

```
#define UART  UART1
#if UART==UART1
# define PIN_TX 9
#elif UART==UART2
# define PIN_TX 2
#else
# warning "UART not correctly defined"
#endif
```

However, UART1 is a memory address with a type cast (e.x. `(uint8_t*)0x004000000`). So the compiler prints some errors.

I made a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define v1 (double)1
#define v2 (double)2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("We have: ");

#define VAL (v1)

#if VAL==v1
  printf("VAL is 1\n");
#elif VAL==v2
  printf("VAL is 2\n");
#else
# warning "VAL not 1 or 2"
  printf("Not defined\n");
#endif
}
```

Which also fails to compile with gcc with the following comments:

```
cc     preproc.c   -o preproc
preproc.c: In function ‘main’:
preproc.c:3:20: error: missing binary operator before token "1"
 #define v1 (double)1
                    ^
preproc.c:10:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘v1’
 #define VAL (v1)
              ^~
preproc.c:12:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAL’
 #if VAL==v1
     ^~~
preproc.c:3:20: error: missing binary operator before token "1"
 #define v1 (double)1
                    ^
preproc.c:10:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘v1’
 #define VAL (v1)
              ^~
preproc.c:14:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAL’
 #elif VAL==v2
       ^~~
preproc.c:17:2: warning: #warning "VAL not 1 or 2" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "VAL not 1 or 2"
  ^~~~~~~
<builtin>: recipe for target 'preproc' failed
make: *** [preproc] Error 1
```

However, if I remove the (double) in the definition of the v1 and v2, it compiles and runs as expected.

---

Note that as an alternative solution I made

```
#define USE_UART1
//#define USE_UART2

#if defined(USE_UART1)
# define UART UART1
# define PIN_TX 9
#elif defined(USE_UART2)
# define UART UART2
# define PIN_TX 2
#else
# warning "UART not correctly defined"
#endif
```

But that involves another variable [edit: technically a macro, but practially another bunch of characters that I have to keep track of].

I was curious to know the rationale behind that compilation error and/or how to solve it, if possible.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you looking for a rationale for? Are you looking for a rationale for why you need to use an auxiliary identifier as a key? That is because the preprocessor is limited. Are you looking for a rationale about why the preprocessor is limited? That is because it is a historical artifact designed to assist in constructing and customizing source code, rather than being a fully integrated part of the language.

Comment: I don't know what bothers you in your final solution. It seems pretty legit to me.

Comment: Your immediate problem is the `double` cast that cannot be interpreted by the **preprocessor** that evaluates the `#if`. Beyond that I am at loss about what you're asking.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I wanted to understand why it does not work. So the rationale. If it is possible, a way to make it work as intended, but Ajay's answer seems to discard that possibility.

Comment: @малинчекуров it does the job, but I find it less elegant. 
Taste and all, I guess.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that's the point that I am asking: why isn't it interpreted. But from the answers and comments, I think I get it.

Comment: Instead of various icky macros, let your HAL define a type such as `typedef volatile uint8_t* uart_t` (could also be an opaque type). Then have each function take `uart_t` as parameter. Define UART1, UART2 etc as physical addresses - a pointer to the first register of the hardware peripheral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4)

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token defined is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined. **After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. ...

In your code you are comparing -

```
#if ((double)1)==((double)1)
```

since `double` is not a valid token, it gets replaced with `(0)`.

Essentially you are comparing -

```
#if ((0)1)==((0)1)
```

Which is not a valid constant-expression because of syntax errors.

When I run this with my compiler `clang`, I get

> error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression

The solution you have mentioned seems like a good one. You should not be worried about "But it involves another variable" because these are not variables but macros. Macros are compile time entities and do no burden your run time in any way (memory, register pressure or even execution time).

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of your working alternative is a common way to approach problems such as this.  Another is to have some sort of configuration program that writes appropriate macro definitions to a header file.

> But that involves another variable [...]

No, there are no variables involved at all.  Preprocessor macros are not variables, they are *macros*.  They do not behave like variables except in a small number of superficial ways.  Supposing otherwise is what led you down a wrong path to begin with.  Macros represent chunks of source code, whereas variables represent storage locations in the running program.